# using ifelse statement to set aes y value in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use an if statement to change the focus of the y aesthetic in ggplot:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = ifelse(TRUE, sym("clarity"), sym("price")))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

But it gives me the following:

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type . Defaulting to continuous. Error in `geom_col()`: ! Problem while computing aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer. Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics are not valid data columns. ✖ The following aesthetics are invalid: ✖ `y = ifelse(TRUE, sym("clarity"), sym("price"))` ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why you are using `sym` here. If you take that part out, you can use one of these two options

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = ifelse(TRUE, clarity, price))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")

# or 

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = if(TRUE) clarity else price)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

The issue is that `sym("clarity")` isn't exactly the same as `clarity`. The former needs to be evaluated to become the latter. Because `aes()` uses non-standard evaluation. you can't directly call something like

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = sym("clarity"))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Rather you need to inject the value into the call with `!!`

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = !!sym("clarity"))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

so I guess if you really wanted to use `sym` you could just inject that value into the expression

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = !!ifelse(TRUE, sym("clarity"), sym("price")))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Note that this doesn't work with `dplyr`'s more cautious `dplyr::if_else` because normally you don't make a vector of symbols. Since you are not working with a vector or values, but just symbol names, it would be better to use `if` that `ifelse` since that's more about control flow rather than transforming vectors.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = !!(if(TRUE) sym("clarity") else sym("price")))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```